# R check if function in a package was called from the package fun or externally

Tags: r, devtools

How can I check from within the package (exported) function if the current function execution has been called by the function from that package or it was called by external package / from global env.

My current approach, developed by experimenting:

```r
myfun <- function(){
    current_call = sys.call()
    parent_call = sys.call(sys.parent())
    if(identical(current_call,parent_call) || !identical(environmentName(parent.env(environment(match.fun(parent_call[[1L]])))),"imports:mypkg")){
        cat("called externally\n")
    }
}
```

Seems to not handle anonymous functions constructed in the other packages which dependent on my package.
Not particularly `devtools` related but package development related which `devtools` address well.

**Edit:**
To goal is to invoke an action (`cat()` in above example) in any cases except the calls from my other functions within the same package.

Comment: Your wording is confusing. I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: You've got an answer below but I'm just wondering if what get's printed out occurs at the beginning or end of the function? If that's the case you could just do something like `.fun <- function(){your_internal_function}` and `fun <- function(){cat("whatever"); .fun()}`

Comment: It would be nice to have an example of an anonymous function constructed in another package to test against.

Comment: @Dason measure timing of the function calls, excluding my package calls. `.fun` wouldn't be possible in my case.

Comment: @JanGorecki It might be possible but I'd have to see the actual use case.  Knowing that though I'd probably just add an extra `verbose` parameter that you have set to TRUE by default that controls whether stuff gets printed.  This would probably be a better approach anyway to allow the user to turn off the printing if necessary.

Comment: @Dason [timing feature for external calls only: #L341](https://github.com/jangorecki/data.table/blob/39bf3c2d9385a8bd8aeb1330e64c039f88823237/R/data.table.R#L341)

Comment: @GSee I've just tested the case of anonymous function from pkgA calling dependent `pkgB::myfun()`. It works OK with solution from your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Borrowing from `data.table:::cedta`, I put these two functions in a package called `test`

```
myfun <- function() {
  te <- topenv(parent.frame(1))
  if(isNamespace(te) && getNamespaceName(te) == "test") { # <-- "test" is the name of the package
    cat("called from my package\n")
  } else cat("Not called from my package\n")
}

tester <- function() {
  myfun()
}
```

After loading the `test` package, I get these results

```
test:::myfun()
#Not called from my package
test:::tester()
#called from my package
```

Comment: Great! looks exactly what I was looking for.